# Specific URLs with SproutCore

Tags: javascript, url, sproutcore

I'm creating an application in SproutCore, which I want to integrate with Facebook. To do this, I need to create a file called `xd_receiver.htm` at `/` (see http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Cross_Domain_Communication_Channel ). But how can I do this (so it's available at `/xd_receiver.htm`)? I'm using sc-server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it'd be possible to easily serve up the xd_receiver.htm file directly with sc-server, but you could put a proxy in your Buildfile (see "Setting Up Your Proxy" at https://sproutcore.pbworks.com/Todos+06-Building+with+Sinatra+and+DataMapper), and point it at some other web server you have (e.g. Apache) serving up xd_receiver.htm.

For production it's usually best for performance reasons to build your SproutCore app (using sc-build) and then host the static files with something that's good at that like Apache. Then you could just configure your web server to provide the SproutCore app and the xd_receiver.htm at the appropriate URLs.